# Select property from each object in a list

Tags: collections, kotlin

Say I have a `List<Tuple>`, where the first element in each is a string. Is there an extension function in Kotlin to select the first element from each of these tuples?

I'm looking for something like the C# LINQ syntax for `Select`:

```
myTuples.Select(t => t.item1)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Kotlin, a Tuple could be a `Pair` or a `Triple`. You could just map over the list and select out the first element, like this:

```
val myTuples : List<Triple<String,String,String>> = listOf(
    Triple("A", "B", "C"), 
    Triple("D", "E", "F")
)
val myFirstElements: List<String> = myTuples.map { it.first } // ["A", "D"]
```

And of course, you can leave off the types, I've left them in to make this easier to follow.